# Printing the repeated values

Tags: php, arrays

How to get rid of repeated values .....

```
foreach($get_all as $key => $value) 
    {
        $v = 1;
        foreach($value as $loc) 
        {
            foreach($loc as $l)
            {
                $new[] = $l['id'];
            }
        }
        $new = array_unique($new);  
        $total = count($new);   
        unset($new);
        if($v)
        {
            $v =0 ;
            $body .= "<tr><td>{$value[0][0]['location']}</td><td>{$total}</td></tr>";
            continue;
        }
    }
```

The above code gives the ouptput:

```
Koramangala 63
Koramangala 63
Indiranagar 36
Koramangala 63
Indiranagar 36
MG Road 16
Koramangala 63
Indiranagar 36
MG Road 16
BTM 35
```

But what i need is :

```
Koramangala 63
    Indiranagar 36
    MG Road 16
    BTM 35
```

What do i have to chage to get the required output?/??

Comment: I didn't get why you are using `$v` and `continue` and the structure of your data. but you can store the values printed in an array and use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check if already printed.

Comment: continue is to stop the current iteration and move on to the next array in $get_all .... but while printing it prints all the values from the beginning.... Look at my output and my required output...

Comment: @bansi : I am not storing the values in any array .... Im just printing it as it is..... Did you understand my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$printed = array(); // initialize an array to store the printed values
foreach($get_all as $key => $value) 
{
    $v = 1;
    foreach($value as $loc) 
    {
        foreach($loc as $l)
        {
            $new[] = $l['id'];
        }
    }
    $new = array_unique($new);  
    $total = count($new);   
    unset($new);
    if($v)
    {
        $v =0 ;
        if (!in_array($value[0][0]['location'], $printed)){ //check if not already printed
            $body .= "<tr><td>{$value[0][0]['location']}</td><td>{$total}</td></tr>";
            $printed[]=$value[0][0]['location']; //store the printed location to the array
        }
        continue; //this is not required as it is the last line
    }
}
```

Note: I don't know why you are using `$v` (may be you have posted the relevant parts only). The structure of your data is not clear so this may not be the best (optimized) option.